Changing the X values in a given data series from an excel chart using Spreadsheetlight
I am creating a program to make an autogenerated chart using spreadsheets light. The only problem is that this library assumes every x value is pegged to the same x value. However, this is not the case in my data, as I am plotting different series with different time scales but comparing them on the same axis.
private void createexcelchart(SLDocument exceloutput, int rowend, int serieslength)
{
    //Takes a spreadsheet value and creates a chart based on that information relevant to the customer.

    SLDocument sl = exceloutput;

    int excelrowheight = serieslength;

    SLChart viscositychart = sl.CreateChart("Compiled Data", 3, 1, serieslength, rowend + 1);

In this case you would plot an axis from the first column "A" and end with the last series dynamically added.
Demonstration showing the wrong series added
I specify which series too add for each of these, but it does not appear that I have the option of switch the x-values.
for (int i = 4; i < rowend + 1; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        SLDataSeriesOptions newgraphobject;
        newgraphobject = viscositychart.GetDataSeriesOptions(i);
        newgraphobject.Line.Width = 1.5m;
        newgraphobject.Marker.Symbol = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.MarkerStyleValues.None;

        //For cycling through each of the colors in the series, causing it to otherwise error out.
        newgraphobject.Line.SetSolidLine(Color.FromName(importedviscositydata.color[seriescolorfinisher]), 0);
        seriescolorfinisher++;

        viscositychart.SetDataSeriesOptions(i, newgraphobject);
        viscositychart.PlotDataSeriesAsPrimaryScatterChart(i,SLScatterChartType.ScatterWithStraightLines);


        seriescounter++;

        if (seriescounter == seriesnumbercount)
        {
            break;
        }

    }

I have toyed with the idea of passing this off the excel interop to then open and redefine the series; but I am struggling on exactly how I would do that.
Does anyone have any idea of what I should do?
Thanks in advance!

TL:DR;I tried going through the options in the spreadsheetlight library, and I tried investigating methods in the excel interop. I could not find a workable solution for either; which may have had to do with my lack of experience with both.
I successfully can graph every series; but all the extra series added to the chart are set to the wrong x-values.
